# How to search sub string in a column in parse table

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a column named as emailId in my parse table. The structure is shown below

```
objectId     emailId
asdsdfdf     abc@gmail.com
agrhxcdf     xyz@gmail.com
qwrtyjdf     abc@gmail.com efg@gmail.com
```

I have some multiple email substring entry in my emailId column with string as column type, for example in row 3 with objectId qwrtyjdf.

I want to search for all the emailId with value "abc@gmail.com"

On using below query i get length as 1.

```
query.equalTo("emailId", "abc@gmail.com");
query.contains("emailId", "abc@gmail.com");
```

I need to know how to query emailId column in parse table such that it should return length as 2, from row 1 and row 3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Parse concatenates multiple conditions in the same Query with AND conjunction which here means - fetch me all records that both equal to `abc@gmail.com` and also contain `abc@gmail.com` as substring. Looking at the source data you provided, only record no. 1 matches this condition.

Instead you need OR conjunction - either equals to `abc@gmail.com` or contains `abc@gmail.com` as a substring. Check for example [here](https://parse.com/questions/combining-queries-or-not-and-modeling-relationships) on how to construct compound queries (OR).

By the way why don't you use just `query.contains()` function. I believe it should match both 1 and 3.

Hope it helps.

---

Update:

ok, assuming the Parse class is called E-mail, I've tried it in Objective-C (which should be similar) and following JS code should also work:

```
 var query = new Parse.Query("E-mail");
 query.contains("emailId", "abc@gmail.com");
 query.find({
   success: function(results) {
     // results contains a list of players that either have won a lot of games or won only a few games.
   },
   error: function(error) {
     // There was an error.
   }
 });
```

Comment: I have tried this before but it didn't worked.Can u suggest u anything else.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check. if it still doesn't work, can you paste your full code so that I can see the context?